# Ubuntu intallion gets hung up on ready when you are

Tags: 10.10

I am doing a full system install. What do I need to do when I see the ready when you are? Because the installion goes no further. Is it looking for some kind of input from me? If so what?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually shown when the installation wants further information from the user, such as information seen before the slideshow.